# routin answer for $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i^{2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, laurent-series

We know that $\sum_{i=1}^{ \infty} \frac{1}{i^{2}}= \frac{ \ \ \pi^ {2}}{6}$. On the other hand   $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i^{2}}$ also is convergent but Does not have a routine answer based on the function. Is there an example of  series such that Both the infinite state and the finite state of that answer are routine?

Comment: The answer is often just left *as-is* or shorthanded as $H_{n,2}$ as found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalizations).  You won't be getting any answer better than that, it doesn't have a clean closed form otherwise.

Comment: Is there an example of this type of series such that Both the infinite state and the finite state of that answer are routine?

Comment: Per the top answer in the linked question... *no*.

Comment: Thank you for answer